# Container Hierarchy

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using Unity as a container and I'm wondering if it can help me solve an issue. I have 2 services, Service1 and Service2. They both depend on another object, lets call it IFoo. I want each service to get their own instance of IFoo but at the same time I don't want everybody else to. Essentially it should be a singleton but scoped. I thought about using a combination of child containers to achieve this but it doesn't work as I hoped. The idea is that IFoo contains some connection details that are specific to Service1 and Service2 and some other container resolved objects. Below is some code which hopefully makes it clearer.

The code that resolves ViewController would only ever know about the parentContainer.

```
var parentContainer = new UnityContainer();
parentContainer.RegisterType<IParentScope, ParentScoped>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

var childContainer1 = parentContainer.CreateChildContainer();
childContainer1.RegisterInstance<IFoo>(new Foo("Unique to Child Container 1"), 
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
childContainer1.RegisterType<IService1, Service1>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

var childContainer2 = parentContainer.CreateChildContainer();
childContainer2.RegisterInstance<IFoo>(new Foo("Unique to Child Container 2"), 
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
childContainer2.RegisterType<IService2, Service2>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

var viewController = parentContainer.Resolve<ViewController>();


public class ViewController
{
    public ViewController(IParentScope parentScope, IService1 service1, IService2 service2)
    {
        ParentScope = parentScope;
        Service1 = service1;
        Service2 = service2;
    }

    public IParentScope ParentScope { get; set; }
    public IService1 Service1 { get; set; }
    public IService2 Service2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain your specific use case, because as I see it, your approach is flawed. Can you update your question and provide details on what it is you are doing (with real class names and code that demonstrates what you're doing)?

Comment: You don't want want Service1 and 2 to share the instance of IFoo, but what about the other services? Are they going to share the instance given to Service1 OR Service2? Why does it need to be Singleton then?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments guys. I perhaps didn't explain it so well but I've realized I can make it work using named registrations like so.

```
var foo1 = new Foo("FOO 1");
        parentContainer.RegisterInstance<IFoo>("Foo1", foo1);

        var foo2 = new Foo("FOO 2");
        parentContainer.RegisterInstance<IFoo>("Foo2", foo2);

        parentContainer.RegisterType<IService1, Service1>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IFoo>("Foo1")));
        parentContainer.RegisterType<IService2, Service2>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IFoo>("Foo2")));
```

A better option I've now discovered it to use the [Dependency("Foo1")] attribute on the Service1 constructor. This allows me to specify a single named dependency.